# Ruby: where has parsedate gone in 1.9?

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime

I believe that older versions of ruby came with a `parsedate` module that allowed best-guess passing of date/time strings.  This doesn't seem to be in ruby 1.9 -- is there an equivalent piece of functionality elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Date.parse
```

?

http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html

Comment: Oh, or rather Time.parse() for date and time.  Cheers.

Comment: Date.parse in Ruby 1.9 is not the same as ParseDate in Ruby 1.8

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem myself. Looking at the 1.8 source parsetime uses another module which is still around. The following works for me using Ruby 1.9 built from ports on FreeBSD.

```
require 'date/format'
require 'time'

text = "Tue Jun 28 11:58 2011"
array = Date._parse(text, false).values_at(:year, :mon, :mday, :hour, :min, :sec, :zone, :wday)
time = Time.mktime(*array)
puts time
```